# Is it possible to use internet from broadband (regular-lan based) and wireless usb card at same time?

Tags: internet, router, networking, connection

I am going to setup backup internet connection, which can be used with primary connection for faster internet access..
So

1.) i can get wired backup connections .. 
so my question is what kind of Router will work? i am having LinkSys Wireless G Home Router.. Is it possible to put 2 internet connections? and use both at same time?? and get higher speed??

or

2.) I can have wireless USB card ... 
But right now i am unable to use both at same time.. internet is accessible with either wired or wireless..

Any other suggestions??

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a second WAN (internet) connection which acts as a **failover** in case the first WAN connection dies.  If both connections are wired links, you need a router that can handle both connections (called **dual-WAN**) and can use both connections at the same time (called **load-balancing**).

This is possible, but the question may be better suited to serverfault.com.

Comment: okay.. if anyone with sufficient writes can move it to Serverfault.com i don't mind it.. :)

Comment: just go ask the same question on SF.  you might get some assistance here, so leave this one here.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to be connected through your wire and through your wireless connection at the same time ? Just checking I didn't misunderstood.

No, I do not think it's possible (from my experience).

How would that work ? 2 IP adresses on the same computer. When router would talk to it, which one would he be reffering to ? ...

I'm not saying it can't (and wasn't somewhere) be done ... just that I haven't seen it so far.

Comment: Okay, I am having the same confusion.. but There can be software which can work as a virtual NIC and use both internet connection..or something like this.... but unable to find.. Lets see..